# Python Web scraping multiple URLs Output CSV

Tags: python, excel, web, screen-scraping

I have literally started with python today, I have managed to get one url to display data in python using.

```
import requests

URL = "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmUJrnabRCMLsnvXNryojLWcysc4WwJCLqWYvJcWADfZFo/chadsJSON/1.json"
page = requests.get(URL)

print(page.text)
```

I need to look up multiple urls (like above but numbered 1-upto 10,000)
and save it as a csv with each url data in one cell I will be able to manipulate the data to make it useable in excel.

Please can anyone make they python code I can run.

Comment: Spend a couple of weeks working through python tutorials, e.g. to learn about loops, how to write to files, etc.

Comment: Thanks luk2302 I will do just that. I just wanted to see some results etc to progress.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple answer but will be very useful in your case although you still need to do some work to reach the required output.

This is how you can send requests from 0 to 100, using a `for` loop:
[For Loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)

```
import requests

for i in range(100):
    URL = "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmUJrnabRCMLsnvXNryojLWcysc4WwJCLqWYvJcWADfZFo/chadsJSON/" + str(i) + ".json"
    page = requests.get(URL)
    print(page.text)
```

And to store the data in a CSV file, I advice you to use `csv` library which is really helpful in that, you can read more in its documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'a+', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["COL1", "COL2"])
```

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud, I am getting a syntax error

Comment: >>> for i in range(100):
...     URL = f"https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmUJrnabRCMLsnvXNryojLWcysc4WwJCLqWYvJcWADfZFo/chadsJSON/{str(i)}.json"
... page = requests.get(URL)
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    page = requests.get(URL)
    ^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
>>> print(page.text)

Comment: I updated the code. It worked on my side, I am using Python 3.9.7 but should work on all python 3.x versions. Can you try again?

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly Thank you, I am sorry I don't understand how to get it to output as a csv?